# Evaluating rational functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry the function field $K(Y)$ of a variety $Y$ is defined as the set of equivalence classes $<U,f>$ with $f$ being a regular function on the open subset $U\neq\emptyset$. We have $<U,f>=<V,g>$ if $f$ and $g$ agree on $U\cap V$.

Now for my question:
How does one evaluate a "rational function on $Y$" $f$? Is it $f(P)$ using the Evaluation map for polynomials? In this case, I don't see that this is well defined: Let $P\in U\setminus V$ and $<U,f>=<V,g>$, then g(P) might not even be defined!

I also wonder what the motivation of the term "rational function on $Y$" is, while an element of $K(Y)$ is in generel just regular on an non-empty open subset of Y.

I have also seen definitions of the function field, not taking the domain into respect, where I assume one takes the largest possible. How is this consistent with Hartshorne and where are my mistakes? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is this: on a variety $Y$, given open subsets $U$ and $V$ and regular functions $f : U \to k$ and $g : V \to k$, if $f |_{U \cap V} = g |_{U \cap V}$, there is a unique regular function $h : U \cup V \to k$ such that $f = h |_U$ and $g = h |_V$. (There's only one thing it can be – you just have to check that it works!) Therefore, in any equivalence class of regular functions, there is a unique maximal representative.

In particular, you can evaluate a rational function at a point $P$ so long as there is *some* representative defined at $P$. They are called rational functions as a matter of tradition, not because they are actually functions. (It is tempting to think of rational functions on $Y$ as being regular maps $Y \to \mathbb{P}^1$, but that doesn't work in general: for example, $x / y$ defines a regular function $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{ (0, 0) \} \to k$, hence a rational function $\mathbb{A}^2 ⤍ k$, but there is no way of extending it to a regular map $\mathbb{A}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^1$.)

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up a lot! So I would define this $h$ via $h(x)=f(x)$ for $x\neq V$ and for $x\neq U$ respectively. This is well-defined, for let $x\in U\cap V$ then $f(x)=g(x)$ by assumption. Let $<U\cup V, j>$ be another representative, such that $j:U\cup V\to k$ has the properties as $h$. Then the two must agree on $(U\cup V)\cap(U\cup V)=U\cup V$ and hence they are equal. Thus, I could (well-)define the Image of $<U,f>$ as the Image of $h$ in the "maximal" equivalence class $<U\cup V,h>$. Just for curiosity: Where does Hartshorne say all this or is it just "clear" to everyone?

Comment: I think it's considered clear. The only non-trivial thing that goes into it is the fact that any two non-empty open subsets have non-empty intersection.

Comment: Ok, thanks. By the way your example above was very instructive to illustrate the concept of a rational function ("evaluate at some (possible) representative") in contrast to regular functions ("polynomial quotient near any point").

Comment: Can someone clear up how x/y is regular on points where $y=0$? I cannot find the representatives?

Comment: Dear Zhen Lin, the function $x / y$ is *not* regular on $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{ (0, 0) \} $: if it were, it would be regualar on all of $\mathbb{A}^2$ (by Hartogs's theorem), which it clearly is not.

Comment: @0CT0: That function is indeed not regular on  $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{ (0, 0) \} $: see my comment to Zhen Lin.